# Implementing a SQL query without window functions

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have read that it is possible to implement anything you might do in a SQL window function, with creative use of joins, etc, but I cannot figure out how. I'm using SQLite in this project, which doesn't currently have window functions.

I have a table with four columns:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
   id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
   x REAL NOT NULL,
   y REAL NOT NULL,
   val REAL NOT NULL,
   UNIQUE(x,y));
```

and a convenience function DIST(x1, y1, x2, y2) that returns the distance between two points.

*What I want:* For every row in that table, I want the entire row in that same table within a certain distance [eg 25 km], with the lowest "val". For rows with the same "val", I want to use lowest distance as a tie breaker.

My current solution is running n+1 queries, which works but is ucky:

```
SELECT * FROM foo;
```

... then, for each row returned, I run [where "src" is the row I just got]:

```
SELECT * FROM foo
  WHERE DIST(foo.x, foo.y, src.x, src.y)<25
  ORDER BY val ASC, DIST(foo.x, foo.y, src.x, src.y) ASC
  LIMIT 1
```

But I really want it in a single query, partially for my own interest, and partially because it makes it much easier to work with some other tools I have.

Comment: imo, This will not be cheap using standard sql ;-/ You end up with a correlated query for each outer row against the entire table. Or a join against every row in the outer table. And for each row tested the distance has to be calculated.

Comment: I actually don't mind if it's fairly expensive; this is being used for some offline analysis. My current solution is also pretty slow, I'm just curious for academic interest how to do it in a single query [also because, as I said, it makes it much easier to work with some of my other tooling]

Answer (score 0):

Use your query to get the ID of the wanted row, then use that to join the tables:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT foo.*,
             (SELECT id
              FROM (SELECT id,
                           x,
                           y,
                           foo.x AS foo_x,
                           foo.y AS foo_y,
                           val
                    FROM foo)
              WHERE DIST(foo_x, foo_y, x, y) < 25
              ORDER BY val, DIST(foo_x, foo_y, x, y)
              LIMIT 1
             ) AS id2
      FROM foo)
JOIN foo AS foo2 ON id2 = foo2.id;
```

Comment: I'm trying this in sqlite, but the correlated subquery doesn't seem to work; I'm getting "no such column: foo.x" when I just run the top-level subquery [select foo.*, (SELECT ...) FROM foo ]. It seems like sqlite only supports correlated subqueries on items in a WHERE clause?

Comment: This looks like a bug in SQLite (accessing `foo.x` should work in both the WHERE and ORDER BY clauses). Just add another indirection ...